# How to Concatenate Strings in MySQL (xeround)

Tags: mysql, sql, xeround

I'm in a Stored Procedure, and I need to concatenate 3 parameters PLUS a static string to create a unique ID for a table.

So the SP has, let's say, p1, p2 and p3 as varchar parameters, and I want to insert a new row in a table with values p1, p2, p3 and the 4th column would be 'ABC'+p1+p2+p3. I'm using || but it doesn't work. It returns 1. How do I concatenate in MySQL (xeround) and, also, do I need to use @p1 as in transact sql? I mean, using p1 worked for the INSERT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** is used for concatenation in `mysql`. So your code should be,

```
CONCAT('ABC', p1, p2, p3)
```

Comment: @Amarundo i can help you in mysql but not in `xeround`. it's new technology to me . sorry.

Comment: I'm such a donkey... I was missing a parenthesis... THANKS!

Comment: xeround is just a MySQL hosting service for ignorami like me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` as explained further [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).